# Bash script: Gzip an entire folder and keep files extensions same

Tags: bash, gzip

I want to gzip every file in a folder recursively and keep the original name and extension after compression.

I have tried sudo `gzip -9 -r folder` however now each file has an .gz extension added to the original such as `2852b65c1d8b.css.gz` while I want to keep the name as `2852b65c1d8b.css` for the gzipped file to upload to Amazon S3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using this does what you want:

```
find folder -type f -exec gzip -9 {} \; -exec mv {}.gz {} \;
```

The 1st exec gzip the files, the 2nd rename them.