# gzip on a folder without changing the file extension

Tags: linux, gzip

So I am using amazon to serve a few files.

I want to gzip these files before I upload them

first I copy templates into a new folder

```
cp -r templates/ templatesGZIP
```

then I GZIP that folder

```
gzip -r templatesGZIP
```

the problem is that this adds .gz to all the file names. so for example homeTemplate.html changes to homeTemplate.html.gz

is there any way when running gzip -r templatesGZIP that I state I want to keep the extensions the same

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bash script: Gzip an entire folder and keep files extensions same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184303/bash-script-gzip-an-entire-folder-and-keep-files-extensions-same)

This would surely help first compress them with gzip and then rename them.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` just does one thing, turns a single file into a gz archive. What you need is a tar.gz file. Your friend is `tar`, which can use gzip as well

```
cp -r templates templatesGZIP
tar czf templatesGZIP.tar.gz templatesGZIP
```

Backround: `tar` does another one thing well: it turns a directory structure into a single file. The `tar` commands above, explained:

- c = create
- z = zipped, default gzip
- f FILE = name of the archive file

Answer (score 1):

after copying the directory

```
find templatesGZIP -type f ! -wholename *images* -exec gzip {} \; -exec mv {}.gz {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stdout` as a temporary buffer and write the output in a file of your choise:

```
gzip -cr templatesGZIP > outputfile.extension
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in gzip to do this.  Using the two-directory method, the following should do the trick

```
for in_file in $(find templates -type f)
do
    out_file="templatesGZIP/${in_file#templates/}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$out_file")"
    gzip -c <"$in_file" >"$out_file"
done
```

With this method, there's no need for the `cp` command.

This has been tested.

One comment on this - it's uncommon to see gzip'ed files without an extension.